# Ruby on Rails - problems with the Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I having trouble with an Ajax response in Rails and I don't know how to go about debugging it.

This code works as expected:

**View**

```
 <div id="<%= dom_id(comment) %>_count">
   <%= Like.where("comment_id = ?", comment.id).count %>
 </div>
```

**.js.erb response**

```
 $("#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>_count").html("<%= Like.where('comment_id = ?', @comment.id).count %>");
```

However, if I add in a link_to, the response stops working. Any help on what might be going on would be greatly appreciated.

**View**

```
 <div id="<%= dom_id(comment) %>_count">
   <%= link_to Like.where("comment_id = ?", comment.id).count, "#" %>
 </div>
```

**.js.erb response**

```
 $("#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>_count").html("<%= link_to Like.where('comment_id = ?', @comment.id).count, "#" %>");
```

Comment: Can you include the actual rendered JS/HTML that comes back in the response, as opposed to including only the view template?

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending that `Like.where("comment_id = ?", comment.id).count` as parameter to whatever action triggers that response js instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Like.where(...).count` call will return an integer from the `.count` method, which will give you the HTML:

```
<a href="/">1</a>
```

Which is equivalent to `http://yoursite.com/` with the visual label `1`. This link will point to your app's root path.

Is that what you intend?

Comment: You sure? `link_to 1, root_path` produces `<a href="/">1</a>` for me

Comment: I'm sorry, I clarified my answer. What I'm getting at wasn't whether or not a valid `<a>` tag would come out of it (a valid tag definitely does come out of the helper), but instead whether or not that's what the author intended to get, as opposed to a link to the `Likes` index page, or some app-specific resource.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, in an attempt to simplify my issue, I left out what was truly causing the problem in my description above.  However, your answer helped me to think through what I was really trying to accomplish and to actually look at the HTML output to debug the issue, so thank you for that!